# How to prevent BREACH attack in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: breach-attack

I have been advised to implement the following items in our ASP.NET MVC Core site to prevent a BREACH attack.  How do you implement them?

- Separate the secrets from the user input.
- Randomize the secrets in each client request.
- Mask secrets (effectively randomizing by XORing with a random secret per
  request).
- Obfuscate the length of web responses by adding random amounts of arbitrary
  bytes.

We have already implemented Anti-Cross Site Forgery Tokens on every form and turned off Http Level Compression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is reported by this tool:

https://www.acunetix.com/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All I did was disabling HTTP compression in IIS and the BREACH ATTACH issue was no longer raise by our security scans.

Comment: @lsa,  how did you Disble HTTP Compression on IIS ?

Comment: Yes I did and it did fix the problem.

Comment: May i know how you did it ?

Comment: What software tool is reporting a 'breach attack'? Please add this to your question. Otherwise your question is pretty unhelpful to anyone else

Comment: Ok, in my case I had a custom attribute developed and applied on controllers for compression here is the link to develop such attribute 'https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/28/gzipdeflate-compression-in-aspnet-mvc', I did disabled compression on IIS, but I guess the compression attribute over writing it. Anyway by removing the custom attribute for compression on controller we are good to go.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Thank you for suggesting google, also please refer to my previous comments; we used 'https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/'.

Comment: I will edit your original question and this infomation. I can't see it anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Isa "Disabling HTTP compression in IIS"

you can find the tips in this [article](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression)

there is a section, titled
"HOW TO ENABLE OR DISABLE STATIC AND DYNAMIC COMPRESSION FOR A SITE OR APPLICATION"

I have disabled the dynamic compression, retested and passed.